# html - the <dd> tag and cheating for a whitespace indent

Tags: html

I am working on a preservation project to migrate some old WordStar text into HTML.

The converter is all completed, and following many discussions and sessions with the curator I am 100% happy that the content has been intellectually and aesthetically transferred to its new format.

Whats troubling me is this...

The WordStar formatted content uses 6 non-breaking whitespace chars (`xa0`) to start every paragraph as an indent.

example:-

`\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0this is a new paragraph`

I have to replicate this in the html (i.e. the paras must start with whitespace lead-in). As a preservation task, we have an obligation and requirement to as replicate the aesthetic features of the original as much as is possible.

When I put the converter together as a work around for this issue, I used the `<dd>` tag to give me a white space equiv in the HTML.

`<p><dd>this is a new paragraph</p>`

As we are about to commit the preserved objects into the preservation repository (where they will become the defacto master in perpetuity), I am keen to make sure that the `<dd>` is the best way to achieve the indent. I can't have any attendant css or other files, the html file must be self contained.

I'm especially interested to know if there is anything in this use of `<dd>` that will cause future compliance issues in html4/5 specs and thus render.

Comment: You're better off writing something to remove those characters from the page than hacking it with dummy elements or CSS, especially if the hack results in invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always just use 6 non-breaking spaces:

```
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;this is a new paragraph</p>
```

Comment: And I have to ask myself why I didn't just do this in the first place... Excellent idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply keep the NO-BREAK SPACE characters (U+00A0), if the data has them, provided that the [character encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset) has been properly declared, as it should be anyway. (There should be no need to convert them to `&nbsp;` entities.)

Using `dd` is unsafe, inaccurate, and inadequate for this case. The [default indentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#lists) of a `dd` element is 40 pixels, so it does not adapt to font size, and it typically corresponds to about 10 spaces, not 6 (assuming a typical default font size of 16 pixels and a typical space width of 0.25 times font size). So, far from being the best way, `dd` is not a way at all.

Note that even in a self-contained HTML document, you can use CSS, within a `style` element. But CSS has no unit corresponding to the width of a space.

Comment: Clear, and useful. Thank you for taking the time to respond. I will reflect your comments in my final versions. I am glad I checked.